# How do you collect input from a <select> form?

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a page using HTML and PHP that accesses a Marina database(containing boats/owners ETC...), but I dont know how to capture and use the choice selected from the drop down `<select>` form and then display all the boats under that owners name(on the same page).

Here is my relevant code...

```
    echo '<form align="left"; top="200"; action="page2.php"; method="post">
            <p>Select an owner:</p>
            <select top="200"; name="form1"; id="form1">';

    foreach($values as $v){
        echo '<option value="'.$v['LastName'].'">'.$v['LastName'].'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>
        </form>
        <form align="left"; top="250">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>';

        $form1 = $_REQUEST['form1'];
        if($form1){//if there is data submitted to the page
        echo '<p>$form1</p>';

    }
```

When I use this code I get an error stating "form1 is an undefined index"

My question is how would I capture the name chosen as a variable from the drop down list when the submit button is clicked? (I apologize as I am very new to HTML and PHP and am only posting here because I cannot find a simple or clear answer anywhere else)

Comment: I would look into a templating engine. Get your code using sprintf & maybe use OOP PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `<input type="submit">` is not part of the same form. Because you create an independent form for the submit button, it only submits that independent form. This independent form does not have the `name` attribute set, so your `$_REQUEST['form1']` will indeed be undefined.

To correct this, simply have the **one** form, which contains both the selection and submission:

```
echo '<form align="left" top="200" action="page2.php" method="post">
        <p>Select an owner:</p>
        <select top="200" name="form1" id="form1">';

foreach($values as $v){
    echo '<option value="'.$v['LastName'].'">'.$v['LastName'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>';

$form1 = $_POST['form1'];
if($form1){ // if there is data submitted to the page
    echo '<p>$form1</p>';
}
```

Note that you also shouldn't have the semicolons separating the HTML attributes; I've removed these. You'll also really want to use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`, as you don't want `$_GET` access. I've changed this as well.

You also might want to consider extracting the logic from your markup, and separating the two out.